# Read variable from other class

Tags: c++, inheritance

i have 2 classes Player and Bullet.

I need to read one variable in Bullet class from Player class. Problem is that when i copy variable it shows only value that was initiated when Player was created and not updating when Player is moving. How can i get access to live variable?

When i cout getPosition from Player class it shows live position, when i cout from Bullet class it shows only value that was initiated when Player was created.

Player:

```
Vector2f Player::PlayerPosition()
{
    return shape.getPosition();
}
```

Bullet:

```
#include "Bullet.h"
#include "Player.h"
 Player a;

Vector2f Bullet::getPlayerPosition()
{
    return a.PlayerPosition();
}
```

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Do you refer the same object from both classes? What is the 'shape' in the Player class?

Could you please provide more details?

Comment: Looks like there's one `Player` object to rule them all called `a`.  It's declared at file-scope in the bullet.cpp file though, so that suggests a problem.  Is there another `Player` declared somewhere?  Did you intend for there to be a single global player like that?

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring a global *Player* instance *a* before the definition of the function *Bullet::getPlayerPosition*, which means that within the scope of that function, the name *a* is referring to that global instance, which may not be the one you're changing elsewhere. In general, if you'd like some variable to be in a function's scope, the best way is usually to pass the variable as a parameter to the function.

So, for example, I think what you want could look something like:

```
#include "Bullet.h"
#include "Player.h"
Vector2f Bullet::getPlayerPosition(const Player& a)
{
    return a.PlayerPosition();
}
```